# Get id of clicked svg path with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I have an SVG map of counties in Massachusetts. The svg file contains paths outlining each county, and each path has the name of the county as its `id`. I need to grab the `id` of the county when it is clicked, so that it can be set to a variable.

**Edit:** The SVG is an external file (it's a map with a ton of path coordinates; it seems like it would be messy to copy/paste the whole thing directly into the HTML, so it's being loaded from the external file). Here is a sample of the svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="co25_d00.css"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20000303 Stylable//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">

<svg id="MACounties"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax" viewBox="12.711167 456.567074 29.566845 18.433033">
<title>Libre Map Project</title>
<g transform="scale(1.0,-1.0) translate(0,-931.567181)">
<g id="Unknown_Area_Type_co25_d00_e00" style="fill:'currentColor';pointer-events:visible;stroke:rgb(1,0,0);stroke-width:0.01;stroke-linecap:round">
    <path id="Essex" d="M34.363079 474.99995L34.363179 474.99967 34.363179 474.99967 34.462128 474.99704 34.596972 474.95046...>
```

**Edit 2:** This is the HTML file where the image is being loaded.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="co25_d00.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

              var container = $("#map");
              var svgUrl    = "co25_d00.svg";
              var xmlDoc;

              $.get(svgUrl)
                .then(injectSvg);

              function injectSvg(xmlDoc) {
                var svg = $(xmlDoc).find("svg");
                container.append(svg);
              };

              $(document).ready(function() {
                $('path').onclick = function() {
                    alert($(this).attr('id'));
                };
              });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share us the SVG Code? Is it embedded or referenced?

Comment: @Matt I don't think you can have event listeners on externally referenced images, I assume you are using an img tag to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I added a snippet of the svg code I'm working with.

Comment: @matt and we're back to, what's the problem? Is the onclick not called? If it is called, does the alert display something you don't expect?

Comment: No alert is coming up at all. It doesn't seem to be reading the svg at all. (The map loads fine, but the click event isn't working)

Comment: OK, that's because there's no path when the ready function runs. The path is not loaded till the injectSVG function runs.

Comment: The issue is probably that you set the `click` handler too early, in your `$(document).ready` function. Try setting the `click` handler after the SVG has been loaded and inserted into the DOM (i.e. in `injectSvg`).

Comment: I just edited my answer below. In jQuery you have a 'click' function to bind the click event, but it's deprecated, I've updated my code to use the on() function, which is used generally to bind events... first param is the event and second is the code to bind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event binding needs to be inside of your callback. Like

```
  $.get(svgUrl)
      .done(function( svgdata ) {
          injectSvg(svgdata);
          $('path').on('click', function() {
              alert($(this).attr('id'));
          });
  });
```

Comment: I've tried that and now the map doesn't load at all.

Comment: sorry... give that a try

Comment: That's the ticket. Thank you!!